# I have a problem with the += operator for my string class it is not correctly concatenating the strings

Tags: c++, string

When I want to concatenate 2 strings the length comes out fine but the data is not showing up properly.

I have already tried using to check if the string is empty and then if its not allocate space and then use the strcpy function

```
DSString& DSString::operator+=(const DSString& src){
    if(src.data != nullptr) {
        char *tmp = new char[length + src.length + 1];
        strcpy(tmp, src.data);
        strcpy(tmp + length, src.data);
        length = length + src.length;
        delete [] data;
        data = tmp;
    }
    return *this;


}
```

I am expecting length to return 8 which it does but Instead of returning HelloSMU it is just returning SMU.

Comment: Think hard, and then decide: Do you want counted strings, or null terminated strings? Because that short snippet sends very mixed signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If object pointed by `this` stored "Hello", then `length` was = 5. You copied there "SMU" twice, second time with incorrect offset.

Strcpy copies trailing zero.
Actual content of memory then is `"SMU\0*****"`, where *  are uninitialized characters.
Now second copy went ahead after trailing zero left by SMU: `"SMU\0*SMU\0"`
For any function that accepts it as null-terminated string, this is `"SMU"`.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the same data twice. And you should use the copy and then the concat function:

```
strcpy(tmp, data);
strcat(tmp, src.data);
```

Also this is very C type of coding. 
I highly encourige you to use the `std::string` and not create your own string implementation. Only for homework it's good, but don't invent the wheel twice.

The C++ way:

```
std::string tmp(data);
tmp.append(src.data);
```

Comment: its the assignment to create a custom string class

Comment: I don't understand why you are recommending using `strcat()`. it can be far more inefficient than using `strcpy()` again.

Comment: by look he implements own string class